# Abort crash with .app made by py2app

Tags: macos, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, py2app

***TL/DR:* My python app bundled with py2app keep crashing.**

I've coded a **python3.5** app with **pyqt5**. It's working perfectly with python3 foo.py, and even when i'm making an app of it with **py2app** in alias mode.

Btw python, pyqt... Have been installed with **MacPort**. And python35 (from MacPort) is the one active. And i've created an empty qt.conf in Contents/Resources.

However when py2app make a standalone of it, the foo.app crash directly.
Doing `./dist/SoundRain.app/Contents/MacOS/SoundRain` returns `[1] the-pid abort the-precedent-cmd`.

Here the report (useful part):

```
System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff957b10ae __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855e4500 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff97e1e37b abort + 129
3   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x00000001072e8c79 0x1072c2000 + 158841
4   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x00000001072ea667 QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 231
5   org.qt-project.QtGui            0x0000000106e5b1b6 QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() + 6278
6   org.qt-project.QtGui            0x0000000106e5b1db QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() + 27
7   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x00000001074a631c QCoreApplication::init() + 204
8   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x00000001074a6237 QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) + 39
9   org.qt-project.QtGui            0x0000000106e5872e QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(QGuiApplicationPrivate&) + 14
10  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x00000001068b17be QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) + 206
11  QtWidgets.so                    0x00000001063a33cf 0x10636d000 + 222159
12  sip.so                          0x000000010953e7d4 0x10953c000 + 10196
13  org.python.python               0x0000000104963442 0x104911000 + 336962
14  org.python.python               0x000000010491b59d PyObject_Call + 97
15  org.python.python               0x00000001049b77db PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21727
16  org.python.python               0x00000001049baf0c 0x104911000 + 696076
17  org.python.python               0x00000001049b2293 PyEval_EvalCode + 81
18  org.python.python               0x00000001049afdb9 0x104911000 + 650681
19  org.python.python               0x000000010495404d PyCFunction_Call + 273
20  org.python.python               0x00000001049b7a7f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22403
21  org.python.python               0x00000001049bb7cb 0x104911000 + 698315
22  org.python.python               0x00000001049b7914 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22040
23  org.python.python               0x00000001049baf0c 0x104911000 + 696076
24  org.python.python               0x00000001049b2293 PyEval_EvalCode + 81
25  org.python.python               0x00000001049d7e09 0x104911000 + 814601
26  org.python.python               0x00000001049d80ea PyRun_FileExFlags + 178
27  org.python.python               0x00000001049d773e PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 469
28  org.pythonmac.unspecified.SoundRain 0x000000010000275b 0x100000000 + 10075
29  org.pythonmac.unspecified.SoundRain 0x000000010000117a main + 650
30  org.pythonmac.unspecified.SoundRain 0x0000000100000be4 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff957b178a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855e158c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855df375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff957b178a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855e158c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855df375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff957b20a2 kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff831a611d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff831a5d85 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff957b178a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855e158c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855df375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff957b178a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855e158c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff855df375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbfc8f8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000050f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfc920  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfc8f8
   r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fff767d11e0  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x000000010759a488  r13: 0x000000010a4b8370  r14: 0x00007fff72a6e000  r15: 0x000000010a4b5400
  rip: 0x00007fff957b10ae  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff767cf038

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Here is my setup.py used by py2app:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['SoundRain.py']
DATA_FILES = [('.', ['resources/'])]
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           "iconfile": "resources/soundrainlogo.icns",
           "includes": ['sip', 'PyQt5._qt']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And if it can be useful, all the import i'm doing in my .py:

```
import sys
import os
import re
# PyQt5 imports
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import (QApplication,  QWidget,        QDesktopWidget,
                                QMainWindow,   QAction,        qApp,
                                QTextEdit,     QHBoxLayout,    QVBoxLayout,
                                QLabel,        QLineEdit,      QPushButton,
                                QFrame,        QFileDialog,    QMessageBox,
                                QInputDialog,  QErrorMessage,  QDialog,
                                QProgressBar)
from PyQt5.QtGui        import  (QPixmap,       QIcon)
from PyQt5.QtCore       import (QSettings,     QObject,        pyqtSignal,
                                pyqtSlot,      Qt)
#import module for soundcloud, music handling, and file downloading
import soundcloud
import urllib
import httplib2
import requests
from mutagen.mp3        import  MP3,           EasyMP3
from mutagen.id3        import  ID3,           APIC
```

I'm kind of lost, any idea why the bundled app doesn't work ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Well, `QMessageLogger::fatal` means that it prints a message about a fatal error. Have you read that message? It's probably telling that the application can't find the platform plugin.

Comment: Well if i launch the .app in command line, i only get in stderr a message saying that the xxx pid was aborted. Nothing more... Am i suppose to read this fatal error somewhere else ?

Comment: No idea what happens when it's with python and, in addition, on the MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I downloaded and imported wx for my standalone app.

Before bundling,

•  PyQt5 package must be in your application's root directory.

•  setup.py must include the line:   package='PyQt5'

Comment: Nope, this is not the problem, PyQt5 folder is already added in the bundled app. However i still tried your way but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after many hours without finding a solution switched to [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). I wrote about my experiences and why I ended up picking PyInstaller over other alternatives in a [blog post](https://fman.io/blog/codesigning-and-automatic-updates-for-pyqt-apps/).